# How to update C# UWP user interface from other Thread/Task with MVVM when working with Stream Sockets?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm, uwp

I am working on Stream Socket.
Basically I am trying to get Multiple Client to connect to one Server and the client can send string of messages to the server side using MVVM style.

I have manage to get it working principle of it to work. The only issues I am facing now is that it does not update on the User Interface (.xaml).

The Listener() code in the Model are use for server side to listen for connected client. I parse in "ClientIp, StatusMessage, ClientMessage" so that from the ViewModel side I am able to get the Information gotten from the Listener code. Finally, I will bind all these information gotten from the ViewModel onto the User Interface(View).

I have tried using DispatcherHelper, but it still did not help solve the problem. Please advise.

Model

```
public async void Start()
        {
            listener.Start();

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Listener();
            });
        }

public void Listener()
        {

            System.Net.Sockets.Socket socketForClient = listener.AcceptSocket();

            if (socketForClient.Connected)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("in listener method");
                Status = true;

                ClientIp = socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine(ClientIp);

                StatusMessage = $"Client {ClientIp} is Connected";
                Debug.WriteLine(StatusMessage);

                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
                System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);

                while (true)
                {
                    string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();

                    ClientMessage = "Message recieved by client:" + theString;
                    Debug.WriteLine(ClientMessage);

                    if (theString == "exit")
                        break;
                }


                streamReader.Close();
                networkStream.Close();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            socketForClient.Close();
            Debug.WriteLine("Press any key to exit from server program");
            
        }
```

ViewModel

```
public string ClientIp
        {
            get => serverPageModel.ClientIp;
            set
            {
                if (serverPageModel.ClientIp != value)
                {
                    serverPageModel.ClientIp = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

public string ClientMessage
        {
            get => serverPageModel.ClientMessage;
            set
            {
                if (serverPageModel.ClientMessage != value)
                {
                    serverPageModel.ClientMessage = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

public async void StartServer()
        {
            serverPageModel.Start();
        }
```

View

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Name="ServerStatus"
                       Text="{x:Bind serverPageViewModel.ServerStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                       Name="ConnectedClientTextBlock"
                       Text="{x:Bind serverPageViewModel.ClientIp, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
                   Name="ClientMessageTextBlock"
                   Text="{x:Bind serverPageViewModel.ClientMessage, Mode=TwoWay}">

        </TextBlock>
```

Comment: It's not clear which bits are in which classes. Also you don't show the use of `Dispatcher`. Note that in general it is a bad idea for code on a background thread to force itself onto some dispatcher. Better for the UI code to handle an event and dispatch itself.

Comment: Hi Peter, are you able to elaborate more or show any examples of how to use UI code to handle an event and dispatch it. 
Thank you.

Comment: You could refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets#an-echo-client-and-server-using-tcp-sockets) about sockets, which counts on the [CoreDispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-19041) class to marshal execution back to the main thread, from which we can update the UI of our apps.